# How do I delete rows from Cassandra table from spark streaming using deleteFromCassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a RDD containing the primary keys of a table. I need to delete the rows in Cassandra table which matches the values in RDD.

I see that there is deleteFromCassandra in spark-cassandra-connector, but unable to use it, deleteFromCassandra is unresolved.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/streaming/DStreamFunctions.scala

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Is unresolved?"

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your use case, you can follow this question, maybe it will help you:
[Delete from cassandra Table in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563809/delete-from-cassandra-table-in-spark)

Comment: Yes that is one way to solve. But if you look at this https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-349
you see that there is a newer better way to delete rows using deleteFromCassandra.