# delete row from table using pyspark on Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

i'm writing pyspark script on Databricks notebook to insert/update/query cassandra tables, however I cannot find a way to delete rows from table, i tried spark sql:

```
spark.sql("DELETE from users_by_email where email_address IN ('abc@test.com')")
```

I also don't see it's possible to delete data using dataframe. is there any workaround?

Comment: Can you check if this is of any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563809/delete-from-cassandra-table-in-spark or https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-392

Comment: Instead of dropping that row you can just filter out that rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the dataframe and filter it:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.sql("SELECT * from users_by_email")
df_filtered = df.filter(f.col("email_address") == "abc@test.com")
```

Then you can save the dataframe with the overwrite option or, also, in a new table.

Answer (score -1):

Spark does not allow `update` and `Delete` Query over dataframe. You need to use Python external API in the code for deletion.

You can check below Python API which provide `.delete()` function for delete.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.18/api/cassandra/cqlengine/models/#cassandra.cqlengine.models.Model-methods

Comment: Thats cassandra api, not pyspark